# Need to create a report using report viewer

Tags: asp.net, report

I need to create a report using Report viewer. unfortunately, I haven't worked on Report viewer before. My SQL query accepts 3 parameters to fetch the data from SQL server. Query would be:

Select col1,col2,col3 from table1 where area='ddlselectedarea' and start_date='01-01-2016' and end_date='31-01-2016'

My UI would be:

```
<section id="content" class="has-btn-bar-btm-fixed"><!-- content -->
        <form runat="server" class="form-horizontal custom-form row">
          <div class="cost-transfer-block"><!-- cost-transfer-block -->
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-10">
                            <h2>Dump by item</h2>


                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <asp:label runat="server" Text="From Site" ID="lblFromSite" class="control-label col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3" ></asp:label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                                            <div class="input-group">
                                                <select class="form-control">
                                                   <asp:DropDownList ID="DdlFromsite" runat="server" ></asp:DropDownList>
                                                </select>
                                                <span class="input-group-addon"><a href="javascript:;">&nbsp;</a></span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>



                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 cst-brd-left">

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <asp:label runat="server" Text="From Date" ID="lblFromDate" class="control-label col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3" ></asp:label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-9  transferdate">
                                            <div class="input-group  date">
                                                <input type="date" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Select Date" >
                                                <span class="input-group-addon"><a href="javascript:;"><img src="images/icon-add-on-2-date.png" alt="" /></a></span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <asp:label runat="server" Text="To Date" ID="lblToDate" class="control-label col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3" >To Date</asp:label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-9  transferdate">
                                            <div class="input-group  date">
                                                <input type="date" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Select Date" >
                                                <span class="input-group-addon"><a href="javascript:;"><img src="images/icon-add-on-2-date.png" alt="" /></a></span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>


                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-2">
                           &nbsp;
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
          </div>
          <!-- /cost-transfer-block -->
            <%--<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
            <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server"></rsweb:ReportViewer>--%>
          <div class="gray-btn-row clearfix">
                <div class="btns-group">
                    <asp:button runat="server" Text="Enter" ID="btnEnter" class="btn btn-dark-blue"></asp:button>
                </div>
          </div>

        </form>          
    </section>
```

Please guide me in designing a report using the reportviewer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The report viewer is a totally new component which needed to be designed using Report viewer or report viewer wizard. You can add any of them from the Add new items pane and bind a data table to that component.

I hope this helps others